# Vuex commit after await won't update state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I've read multiple similar questions about this here and elsewhere, but I can't figure it out.

I have a form with `mapGetters` and input values that should update based on Vuex state:

```
    ...mapGetters({
      show: "getShow"
    }),
```

sample form input (I'm using Bootstrap Vue):

```
      <b-form-input
        id="runtime"
        name="runtime"
        type="text"
        size="sm"
        v-model="show.runtime"
        placeholder="Runtime"
      ></b-form-input>
```

Then I have this method on the form component:

```
    async searchOnDB() {
      var showId = this.show.showId;
      if (!showId) {
        alert("Please enter a showId");
        return;
      }
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("searchShowOnDB", showId);
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        alert("error searching on DB");
      }
    },
```

and this action on the store:

```
    async searchShowOnDB({ commit, rootState }, showId) {
      var response = await SearchAPI.searchShowOnDB(showId);
      var show = {
        show_start: response.data.data.first_aired,
        runtime: response.data.data.runtime,
        description: response.data.data.overview
      };
      //I'm updating the object since it could already contain something
      var new_show = Object.assign(rootState.shows.show, show);
      commit("setShow", new_show);
    }
```

mutation:

```
    setShow(state, show) {
      Vue.set(state, "show", show);
    }
```

searchAPI:

```
export default {
    searchShowOnDB: function (showId) {
        return axios.get('/search/?id=' + showId);
    },
}
```

Everything works, the API call is executed, I can even see the Vuex updated state in Vue Devtools, but the form is not updated.
As soon as I write something in an input field or hit `commit` in Vue Devtools, the form fields `show_start`, `runtime`, `description` all get updated.

Also, this works correctly and updates everything:

```
    async searchShowOnDB({ commit, rootState }, showId) {
      var show = {
        show_start: "2010-03-12",
        runtime: 60,
        description: "something"
      };
      //I'm updating the object since it could already contain something
      var new_show = Object.assign(rootState.shows.show, show);
      commit("setShow", new_show);
    }
```

I don't know what else to do, I tried by resolving Promises explicitly, remove async/await and use `axios.get(...).then(...)`, moving stuff around...  nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe try doing a reproduction of the issue but on a smaller scale and share with us please :) Via CodeSandbox or JSFiddle

Comment: I reproduced it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sun-yjl36 - new window: https://yjl36.csb.app/ - just enter a name and hit search. Nothing will change. then as soon as you edit the input, what I need will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line `15` of your `/modules/search.js` you're using `Object.assign()` on `rootState.search.show`. This mutates the `search` prop of the `state` (which is wrong, btw, ***you should only mutate inside mutations***!). Read below why.

And then you're attempting to trigger the mutation. But, guess what? Vue sees it's the same value, so no component is notified, because there was no change. This is why you should ***never*** mutate outside of mutations!

So, instead of assigning the value to the state in your action, just commit the new show (replace lines `15-16` with:

```
 commit('setShow', show);
```

See it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hooks-kplp7?file=/src/modules/search.js

This will completely replace `state.show` with `show`. If you only want to merge the response into current `state.show` (to keep some custom stuff you added to current `show`), you could spread the contents of `state.show` and overwrite with contents of `show`:

```
commit("setShow", { ...rootState.search.show, ...show });
```

Also note you don't need `Vue.set()` in your mutation. You have the `state` in the first parameter of any mutation and that's the `state` of the current module. So just assign `state.show = show`.

And one last note: when your vuex gets bigger, you might want to [namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) your modules, to avoid any name clashes.

Comment: got it! I guess I got `Object.assign()` wrong: I thought it only returned the updated object without changing it. Thanks! I will also namespace my modules.

Comment: @koichirose [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)'s main job is to assign (to mutate the object passed in as first argument). The fact that it also returns the mutated object is more of a nice feature (a byproduct, if you want), as you don't have to run that assignment as a separate expression. You can actually run it inside another expression and use the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

All props of objects in a state that is used in templates must exist or you should call Vue.set for such properties.

```
  state: {
    show: {
      runtime: null // <- add this line
    }
  },
```

You call Vue.set for the whole object but it already exist in the state and you do not replace it by a new one you just replace props. In your case you have an empty object and add the 'runtime' prop it it using Object.assign.
Also all manipulations with state should be done in mutations:

```
      var new_show = {
        runtime: response.data.url
      };
      commit("setShow", new_show);
...
  mutations: {
    setShow(state, new_show) {
      Object.assign(state.show, new_show)
    }
  },
```